# I have to setup an existing react native project in my system

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, visual-studio

"/Users/rahul/Downloads/stylist-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector/InspectorInterfaces.cpp Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/rahul/Downloads/stylist-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector/InspectorInterfaces.cpp'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?"

This is the issue I face while launching the app from Xcode.

I was expecting that my app would launch in the Xcode simulator after I clean the build and run the app. I upgraded the react native version from 0.60.2 to 0.72.6.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall node_modules

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install`

Comment: the npm install command isn't working

Comment: Is there an yarn.lock file or an Package-lock.json?